# What's grammatically wrong in this question: "Why China has less population than India?"

Tags: questions, word-order

> Why **China has** less population than India?

Shouldn't it be like:

> Why **has China** less population than India?

OR

> Why **do** China **has** less population than India?

Comment: What's your take on it? *"Why **does** China **have** less population than India?"*

Comment: Loosely related: [“Why had you to” or “why did you have to”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17173/why-had-you-to-or-why-did-you-have-to)

Comment: I think a better way of putting it is "Why **does** China **have a** lower population than India?"

Comment: We've just had a [nice discussion of this question in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25809039#25809039).

Comment: You should use *a* as @RileyFrancisco suggested. It'd be even better to use *a smaller population*. BTW, I think your sentence is not factually correct.

Comment: It's a good thing you noticed that, @Damkerng T. (I mean the fact) Maybe the OP refers to a particular niche though. Or even questioning that 'fact' - hence, the 'why'.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Should I used gerund with "comfortable" in this sentence: I'm not comfortable using complex words and sentences. ? (I want to use "use" verb only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English is dependent on word order to get meaning across.

We simply do not form *questions* that way (note, the clause structure would be fine as a declarative, such as the title of a book or article).

Instead we would structure the question this way, most commonly in American English:

> Why does China have less population than India?

The following is also grammatical, but I'd never say it like this:

> Why has China less population than India?

The second one sounds British or old fashioned.

Comment: @Rathony We welcome you back and expect you to contribute in a fair way using better words. 'I don't think so...'; 'I'd disagree...' are preferable over 'You are wrong!'

Comment: The funny thing, @MaulikV, is that *Had lunch?* depends on word order and it is not ungrammatical.... (Maybe you are familiar with the advertising slogan *Got milk?*) Anyway, the user has had her/his account suspended again, this time for a month.

Answer (score 3):

1. Word order in interrogative sentences is different - not the usual Subject-Verb-Auxillary-Object but Verb-Subject-Auxillary-Object.  "Auxillary" here is the second (and third if applicable) word of any verb that has an auxillary or helping verb.

> I was throwing a brick.
>
> Was I throwing a brick?

2. Interrogative sentences normally use *do + verb* unless the verb is *to be* or the verb uses *have* as an auxillary.  Per above, the subject will come between *do* and the verb as you can see below:

> I am awesome.
>
> Am I awesome? (verb is *to be* so *do* not needed)
>
> She ran away quickly.
>
> Did she run away quickly?
>
> He had ran away very quickly.
>
> Had he ran away very quickly?  (*have* is an auxillary in *to have run* so *do* not needed)
>
> I have 3 marbles.
>
> Do you have 3 marbles?  (*have* is NOT an auxillary so *do* is needed)
>
> Have you 3 marbles?  (Agree with @NES, sounds very formal, British or old fashioned)
>
> I went to the park.
>
> When did I go to the park?  (second words in auxillary verbs do not change with the first word)
>
> China has less population than India.
>
> Why does China have less population than India.
>
> They had been walking for 2 hours.
>
> Had they been walking for 2 hours? (*have* is an auxillary in *have been walking* so *do* not needed)

3. Note that "China" is a singular noun so it takes singular verbs.

Answer (score 0):

None of your alternatives is correct. For a start: population is not more/less, it is higher/lower.

Secondly, none of the three sentences uses a valid interrogative form. The only valid one is does + have in this case (because, as someone already pointed out, in this case "have" is not auxillary), not do + has. The third person goes in the auxillarry verb,  i.e:

*Why **does** China **have** a lower population than India?*

Comment: *Why has China less population than India?* is a valid interrogative structure.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Should I used gerund with "comfortable" in this sentence: I'm not comfortable using complex words and sentences. ? (I want to use "use" verb only).

Comment: *I'm not comfortable using complex words and sentences* is fine.