# Have got in BrE

Tags: british-english

I am really confused now, so I've found out that:

Facts :

HAVE GOT is only used in the present and past form.

the plain "have" is used in all tenses.

HAVE GOT cannot be combined with the modal verbs such as :must, may, might, can, etc. and can't be combined with to+infinitive.

Only the plain "have" can be combined with the modal verbs & it can be combined with to+infinitive. ex. I want to *have* a pair of shoes (or) I want to have got a pair of shoes.

HAVE GOT and the plain "have" are used in BrE. (Do BrE natives use both ? Could you explain the differences between them?)

The pattern

A. HAVE GOT : I have got.. & I haven't got..& have I got (in the negative, haven't I got ___ ?)

B. HAVE : I do have.. / I have.. & I don't have.. & do I have? (negative, don't I have?)

C. past : I had got /(I did have) I had & I hadn't got /I didn't have & had I got (hadn't I got?), did I have? ( didn't I have?)

Are these facts correct?
I await your explanations, thanks.

Comment: I quoted CGEL once on *have got*. It may be useful to you. https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/89856/3281

Comment: Hi! That was my post that I posted it 4 hours ago, so I have edited my question with more new facts. Check them out.

Comment: Hi @Lambie , so, can I use to+ have got

Comment: You asked the same kind of questions on our sister site ELU.

Comment: You are making additional accounts, posting multiple copies of your question instead of editing, and posting answers that do not answer your question.  Please don't do these things.  If you'd like to edit your question, please use the [edit] link.

Comment: @Aqsha Isham You need to post an example of a sentence: BrE: He seems to have got rich. AmE: He seems to have gotten rich. Not present and have got/have gotten here is from get meaning to become. So, I don't know what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Aha. This question is very interesting and unless one has thought about it or taught English, the answer is not obvious.

Here we go: In English (all varieties), there are **two ways to say have in the sense of possess in the simple present tense**:

**I have** a car and I **have got a car**.

Despite what people may try to say via google et alia both **forms in the present simple are used in BrE and AmE** though one might be tempted to say differently.

(Some time ago, some lady who thought she could teach grammar on a very well-known professional site on the Internet was claiming that phrases like "Got Milk" used in a now famous ad were ***bad grammar***. In fact, "Got Milk" is just a shortening of: [Have] you got milk? In speech, the have is sometimes dropped.

Here's **the RUB**: The **simple past tense in BOTH** is: **had**.
For example: I **had** a car last week. I **didn't have** a car last week. **Did I** have a car last week? The auxiliary is did.

BUT: The **present perfect tense** **is not the same** (repeat, not the same) **in BrE and AmE**. For example:

He's got a lot of money recently. [verb: to own or possess] [BrE]

He's gotten a lot of money recently. [verb: to own or possess] [AmE].

In the present perfect tense, Brits use **have got** regardless of the fact they use either **have got** and **have** in the present and Americans use **have gotten**. The **participle gotten is not used in modern BrE**.

**Therefore, the British use of have got can be present simple OR present perfect**.

When you first hear this, unless you realize what is going on, you might mistake the tenses here if you have not been told that gotten is not used in BrE.

To an American (trained and/or educated ear), when **you hear the BrE speakers use have got as a present perfect tense, you feel as if something is missing**. It is not. That's just the way it is.

**All the tenses EXCEPT for the present prefect with gotten in AmE are exactly the same on both sides of the pond**.

Modals; generally, yes, the modals used with the verb have meaning to own or possess) in the present are used like this:
He must/can/might/should/could/may have [possess] some milk in the fridge. For own or possess, only HAVE, no have got.

But careful, with the verb GET: must have got, should have got, could have got [past tense] in BrE would be: must have gotten, should have gotten, etc. in AmE.

So when **get** is  used in the present perfect as BUY (or other meanings of get) something, for example, one can have:

He **must have got** [bought] some wine for the party. [BrE]

He **must have gotten** [bought] some wine for the party. [AmE]

This is the verb get, but that can be confusing if one is not aware of it. Don't confuse the present perfect of GET [have got] with the present tense have/have got (possess).

As for the infinitive: I have got to buy a car or I have to buy a car are both the same meaning. Both are present simple and both are AmE or BrE. But the meaning here is DIFFERENT. To have to [do something]; have got to [do something]. That is, be obliged to do something.

Comment: BrE speakers will tend only to use "gotten" in fossilized phrases like "ill-gotten gains"

Comment: That is not relevant here. That is an adjectival use.

Comment: This would be relevant "Marckwardt 1958 points out that to
many—perhaps most—Americans have got denotes
mere possession, while have gotten donotes obtaining" - Webster's Dictionary of English Usage (c.c @Calchas)

Comment: /have gotten/ in AmE is the present perfect of the **verb to get** (which means: to obtain, buy, receive, etc.) In Britain, the present perfect of the verb to get is have got. It is also in Britain, like in the states, one two present forms of have. That's why this is confusing to ELL's.

Comment: correction: one of two forms.

Comment: AmE:  _"He has gotten a lot of money recently."_ would not mean he has [owned or possesed].  It would mean that he has _come into possession of_ the money, with no implication one way or the other that he kept it.  _He has gotten praise for being so friendly at work.  He also  has gotten several bonuses from his boss, but he always blows them on twinkies right away."_

Comment: I have covered this extensively in my answer and in my last comment, and now I am doing it again: to get with the meaning of receive in AmE and BrE are the same thing. The difference is the present perfect of to get. AmE=I have gotten, BrE=I have got. The present perfect of /to get/ and to have/have got in BRITISH English are both: have got.

Comment: @Lambie So, do they have different meaning? E.g. Jane wants to have got a new house. (or) she wants to have a new house.

Comment: Which can I use for expressing "possess" (to-infinitive) (to-have got/to-have)? : e.g. My father wants to have a car. (or) my grandfather wants to have got a car. @Lambie , do they have same/different meaning?

Comment: @Aqsha Isham: I will say this once: the verb to have (possess) has TWO FORMS in the present tense in English: have, helping verb do/does AND have got, helping verb has/have. My father HAS GOT a car=My father has a car. BUT ONLY: wants to have. My father wants to GET a car.

Comment: Do  you understand helping verb? **Do** you have a car. ***Have*** you got a car. Do and have are helping verbs here. Separately from that, the verb GET on its own means receive, purchase, buy, obtain. Do you get it? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's plain and clear once you understand and the first thing is that **Have got** and **Have** are identical:

1. - **Have got** is commonly **British English**.
   - **Have** is commonly **American English**.
2. **Have got** is more common in informal **American English**.
3. With **Have got** in very informal English the word **have** may be omitted.

   - I got a big house. - ***'ve (have)*** is omitted.
4. Since **have got** is mostly informal, it will almost always be contracted.

Comment: I'm sorry but this BrE and AmE usage you claim exists, simply does not. There are two simple present forms for the verb to have in English. Also, this is not so easy to understand if you bring the present perfect into the picture. And have got is not "mostly informal".

Comment: Here is an example from The Guardian newspaper: Those who assume that the obsolescent diplomacy of the 20th century – as it is described by today's global network enthusiasts – was conducted entirely behind closed doors by elites have got their history wrong.https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2010/mar/28/diplomacy-technology

Comment: I'm with Lambie, though many usage panels believe that "have got" is more common in BrE than AmE, it's not strictly true. The "got" is just sometimes added when the "have" is unstressed(contracted).

Comment: I really wonder where this myth arose. It is very widespread. As a translator, I see it all the time in translation forums and my non-native English speaker friends. Yet, here I sit in the US, and I hear it every single day, just about. :)

Comment: It is absolutely correct that *have got* is less common in AmE.  It's quite common in AmE, but significantly more common in BrE, and in many cases AmE speakers say *have* when BrE speakers would say *have got*.  See Biber et al 1999 for a corpus-based description of the distribution in both dialect groups.

Comment: Do you know the AmE ad: Got Milk? It's built on [have you] got milk? And I really pay attention to what people say around me and not corpus-based descriptions. Corpi cannot take people talking here, there and everywhere into account. A corpus is usually written language. In fact, you can't really measure have/have got in speech.  You can only hear instances of it.