# Verb “got” without verb “have”: “Got any kids, Detective?”

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs

I met unusual situation when I was reading some text. On the secret it was gamescript from mafia.
I know what in Present Perfect has such form of usage:

- In assertation: Face + have/has + verb in third form
- In question: Have/Has + face + verb in third form

Next look at the gamescript sentences:

> 1. Got a business proposition for you, detective.
> 2. Got any kids, detective?

Instead that I expected to see it:

1. I have got a business proposition for you, detective.
2. Have you got any kids, detective?

Can you explain what is here happening? What kind of time in English have these sentences?

Comment: Can you explain in simple English what this is all about?

Comment: @RonaldSole what exactly you did not understand?

Comment: By simple it will be: what difference between Got any kids, detective? vs Have you got any kids, detective?

Comment: Brusque: **Got any kids, detective?** Polite: **Have you got any kids, detective?**  Politer: **Do you have any kids, detective?** Best matched to character and context.

Comment: In other words, it is simply very casual speech, omitting some words which the listener is expected to supply in their own mind. "Want a coffee?" "Like my new jacket?"

Comment: @KateBunting It is interesting way because I always build my sentences by the english rules.

Comment: duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127834/have-got-in-bre/127842#127842 [Engish with a capital c, Russian with a capital r]

Comment: This kind of very informal speech ignores the rules of English! You shouldn't imitate it until you are a very confident speaker.

Comment: @KateBunting I will get it in my attention

Comment: @Lambie nice explanation, I like it

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to write that and, of course, unless you have taught English or been an editor, it is not so apparent....